# Using Euler-Lagrange equations to differentiate a Laplacian

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

Assume I am given a functional of the form:
$$
I_0[u]:= - \int \nabla u \cdot \nabla u dx 
$$
then, I know that by the Euler-Lagrange equations, I have:
$$
\frac{\delta I_0}{\delta u }= 2\Delta u 
$$

But, what if I have higher-order derivatives inside the functional? For example, what is the variational derivative $\frac{\delta I_2}{\delta u }$ of the functional:
$$
I_1 [u]:=\int \Delta u dx
$$
or
$$
I_2 [u]:=\int (\Delta u)^2 dx
$$
?

Hope I made myself clear.

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Euler-Lagrange equations implicitly assume that you have a functional which is of the form $I[y,y';x]=\int f(y,y',x)dx$. To do this, we use a Taylor expansion, incrementing $y$ by a small amount $\delta y$: $$\int_{a}^{b}f(y+\delta y,y'+\delta y',x)dx\\=\int_{a}^{b}f(y,y',x)dx+\int_{a}^{b}\left(\delta y \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+\delta y' \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\right)dx\\=\int_{a}^{b}f(y,y',x)dx+\int_{a}^{b}\delta y\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}\right)dx$$
Where we neglected any quadratic and higher order terms. Clearly, if $f$ depends on second (order higher) order derivatives, you would need to do a different Taylor series expansion (of a similar kind). I'll leave that as an exercise. For example, if $f$ depends on $y''$ as well, Euler-Lagrange becomes $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}-\frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y'}+\frac{d^{2}}{dx^{2}}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y''}=0$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but I still have the following misunderstanding :
Will you please explain your last equality ? Why does $\frac{\delta y' }{\delta y } = - \frac{d}{dx}$ ? 
 
Thank you very much

Comment: That actually comes from integration by parts - do you want to try to see it or shall I write it out?

Comment: I think I will try , but before I will do that:
is it true that $\int \delta y' = \delta y $ ? Can this be formally proved?

Comment: i.e., as far as I see, you did:
$$
\int \delta y' \frac{\partial f}{\partial y' } = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y'} \int\delta y' - \int \left(  \frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y '} \cdot \int \delta y' \right) 
$$
which leaves me the question of whether indeed:
$\int \delta y' = \delta y $ ? THanks !

Comment: Indeed, the change $\delta y$ in $y$ induces a change $\delta y'=(\delta y)'$ in $y'$.

Comment: (That is, you're right)

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot !